# I need to retrive data's from start date to end date using parameters in getrequest postman

Tags: api, postman

Trying to retrive data from date to date for api testing using postman.  I need to use get method and from and to date in url parameter. Please help me.[following is the code i am trying[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imzIk.jpg)

Comment: So, what do you want is creating datetime in ISO format, then put it in URL as a query param?

Comment: want to retrieve data with start and end date. i am using this http://{{api-host}}/serviceleveloutcomes/?start-2021-01-10&end=2022-01-10                                                         its not working

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean and your problem is.